# Joomla 3-article is published but not showing

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, beginner

I'm a newbie to Joomla 3 and I have installed it on my PC using Wamp 2.5. I published an article, but the article is not showing on the website. What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: How do you try to access the article? So what do you mean by "not showing on the website"?

Comment: @Mainz007: I try to access the article by going to my website. For publishing the article I go to Content--->Article Manager--->Add New Article. I publish the article but it's not visible on the website.

Comment: I am not sure if is a setup failure or a bug, but none of my single articles are not displayed when are accessed in from the menu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Articles in Joomla are usually displayed through **Menu Items**. Creating and publishing an article is only the first step, you also have to create a menu item:

[image: How to add a menu item in Joomla]

These are some of the most popular menu types:

**Articles → Featured Articles**

This will show all your *featured articles* (marked with a star in the article list).

**Articles → Single article**

This will let you choose a single article which will be displayed on your website for the menu item.

**Articles → Category blog**

This will display all articles from a chosen category. If the articles has a *Readmore* tag (inserted using the <kbd>Read more</kbd> button below the article editor), only the first part of each article will be displayed, followed by a link to the full article. This is the simplest way to create a blog in Joomla.

[image: Display articles in Joomla]